# View contents of array in Visual Studio (assembly language)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, x86, masm

In Visual Studio, is it possible to view the contents of an array when debugging assembly language code? I already know how to add the array `num` to the "Watch" window, but I'm still trying to figure out how to watch the contents of the array. It's possible to add a `sword` array to a the "Watch" window in Visual Studio, but is it possible to view the contents of an array while stepping through the program?

```
.686p
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 2048
.data
num   sword  1000,-1000,2000,-2000 ;I want to keep track of each value in this array while debugging.
;Is it possible to display the contents of all indices of num while debugging?

ExitProcess proto, exitcode:dword
.code

start:![Lots of ?'s are showing up here instead of the actual value of the array][1]

mov ax, num;
mov ax, [num+1];

invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display the memory occupied by your array.

- go to the "memory1" tab next to "auto", "locals", etc
- type in the symbol name you want to inspect, or select the variable name in the source and drag it to the `Address` field of the memory window. That is the way I use to do while debugging C code, as I first test it with assembly it appears that I needed to type it "in the C style", that is enter `&num` to display the address of the `num` symbol.
- you can customize the word size to display (from 1 to 8 bytes per word) by right-clicking on the window, and you can choose the number of displayed columns in the toolbar options of the window

Comment: The "memory1" tab isn't showing up for me. How can I add it to the tabs that are displayed?

Comment: Indeed, I used to show it through the debug / windows menu but it my express 2010 edition it seems to have vanished. You can display it again with the command `memory` entered in the `command window` (close to `immediate`)

Comment: It seems to be working now - I just need to type `&` before the name of the array in order to see the contents of the array.

Comment: Also, is it possible to add a specific address of an array to the Watch window?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: as it supports "C" expressions, you can try `&array+42`